# All single bot multiple apps messaging extensions commands are displayed when using a single app @mycustomappname

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

we have one bot, but multiple messaging extension apps with multiple commands that uses the same bot. I'm calling app in compose box by typing @mycustomappname then choosing a command. The problem is that all same bot commands from multiple apps are displayed, but should be displayed only one app commands. is this expected? thanks.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For consistent behavior the search messaging extensions should be invoked from buttons from bottom of  Compose message area and Command box. If you call from compose area by @mention the bot you well get all multiple commands of different apps.

[image]

Comment: thank you for the answer. The same is not only for search messaging extensions but also for the action messaging extensions. Are there any plans to improve the behavior of app @ mention to only show app related actions?

Comment: @Saulius - we recommend you to raise a Teams UserVoice [here](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/) if this needs to be consider as a future request.